# kernel modules missing

Tags: kernel-modules, firewall

I'm using this [NPi i.MX6ULL](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/NPi-i.MX6ULL-Dev-Board-Linux-SBC/#introduction-to-software) (armhf) board here. It comes with a customised linux distribution, based on Debian Buster. But it's been completely stripped down to the bare minimum.

My question isn't related to the board, it's more about the linux kernel. I was trying to get a firewall up and running on it, but nothing was working. I've found that there's a lot of common kernel modules missing (see lsmod output below).

So basically I understand that I'm missing the nf_tables and ip_tables modules. But now my stupid question is -- how do I add them? Where do I get them from? I've 'apt install nftables' and all other sorts of things. But nothing adds the modules in there.

Any help? Thanks!

```
debian@npi:~/libmnl$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

```
debian@npi:~/libmnl$ uname -r
4.19.71-imx-r1
```

```
debian@npi:~/libmnl$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
imx_wm8960             16384  0
snd_soc_wm8960         40960  0
snd_soc_fsl_sai        24576  0
imx_pcm_dma_v2         16384  1 snd_soc_fsl_sai
snd_soc_fsl_spdif      24576  0
snd_soc_fsl_asrc       45056  0
imx_pcm_dma            16384  1 snd_soc_fsl_spdif
snd_soc_core          147456  7 snd_soc_fsl_asrc,snd_soc_fsl_sai,imx_pcm_dma_v2,snd_soc_fsl_spdif,imx_pcm_dma,snd_soc_wm8960,imx_wm8960
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  3 imx_pcm_dma_v2,imx_pcm_dma,snd_soc_core
snd_pcm                98304  9 snd_soc_fsl_asrc,snd_soc_fsl_sai,snd_pcm_dmaengine,imx_pcm_dma_v2,snd_soc_fsl_spdif,imx_pcm_dma,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_wm8960,imx_wm8960
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
evbug                  16384  0
dht11                  16384  0
touch_gt9xx            61440  0
```

```
debian@npi:/lib/modules/4.19.71-imx-r1$ ls
kernel             modules.builtin      modules.dep.bin  modules.softdep
modules.alias      modules.builtin.bin  modules.devname  modules.symbols
modules.alias.bin  modules.dep          modules.order    modules.symbols.bin
debian@npi:/lib/modules/4.19.71-imx-r1$ cd kernel/
debian@npi:/lib/modules/4.19.71-imx-r1/kernel$ ls
crypto  drivers  fs  lib  sound
```

Comment: 1/ How do you "understand that you are missing nf_tables and ip_tables" **support**. iptables support is not necessarily built as a module, it can well be built in kernel (I personally prefer this option.

Comment: 2/ To check, I recommend that you cd /usr/src/linux or wherever your active kernel sources are installed, then make menuconfig, then review (at the very least) the IP:Netfilter configuration under the Networking support / Networking option / Network packet filtering path.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add them if you get the complete source of your kernel and also its `.config` file (thought the latter might not be required). In this case you may edit `.config` and enable the missing kernel modules.

If you are lucky enough you could try downloading this [kernel source](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.71.tar.xz) from kernel.org and then compiling it using a cross-build compiler (I'm not sure what this board architecture is - you have omitted it), e.g. `sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi`. In a perfect world you should use the same compiler version as the one used to build your kernel or otherwise modules may trigger a kernel panic/OOPs due to a different ABI.